# Way to run an entire Jenkins pipeline, start to finish, inside a Docker container?

Tags: docker, jenkins, groovy, terraform, pipeline

Is there a way to **define the container where your entire pipeline stages and steps can run, from start to finish**, without having to fire up a container each time you want a stage to run?

The reason for this is that I am running *terraform*, which requires a set of steps to execute before running the deploy (init, plan, apply). One could, of course, run each stage separately and call docker to run a container each time but that would be counter intuitive. Moreso data would be lost, unless  you save `terraform plan` output as an artifact, for example.. which is like scratching your left ear with the right hand, around your head.

I'd like to run the container at the top, then build each stage inside, without killing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define your docker container in the [agent section](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#agent) at the top-level of your Jenkinsfile :

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'terraform-image'
        }
    }
    stages {
        ....
    }
}
```

Each stage will run in the same docker container and you will not lose your workspace between each stages.

Comment: do i need any extra configuration on the Jenkins node? will it know to pick a slave with docker installed and spawn the docker container there automatically ?

Comment: You can add a `label` with the correct label of your docker node inside the `docker` block.